# echo an array in php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am creating the following object from the `bigCommerce` api as follows:

```
[
{
    "id": 412,
    "option_id": 37,
    "display_name": "testSteveMemory",
    "sort_order": 0,
    "is_required": true
},
{
    "id": 413,
    "option_id": 34,
    "display_name": "Hard Drive (desktop)",
    "sort_order": 1,
    "is_required": true
},
{
    "id": 414,
    "option_id": 24,
    "display_name": "Include Keyboard & Mouse",
    "sort_order": 2,
    "is_required": true
},
{
    "id": 415,
    "option_id": 33,
    "display_name": "Memory",
    "sort_order": 3,
    "is_required": true
}
]
```

I convert this to a PHP array using :

```
$curlProductOptions = json_decode($curlProductOptions, true);
```

I then loop through the array and get the option for that option_id

```
$allOptions = array();  
foreach($curlProductOptions as $value){
    //echo $value['option_id'].'<br>';
    $option_id = $value['option_id'];


$product_url = $url.'/api/v2/options/'.$option_id.'/values.json';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $product_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
$curlProductData = curl_exec($curl);
array_push($allOptions,$curlProductData);
curl_close($curl);
}
```

I am then using echo to output the array $allOptions and I consume this in a mobile applications as json.
if I use

```
echo $curlProductData.'<br>'
```

I get the following:

```
[{"id":112,"option_id":37,"label":"1 gig ram","sort_order":0,"value":"1 gig ram"},{"id":113,"option_id":37,"label":"2 gig ram","sort_order":1,"value":"2 gig ram"},{"id":114,"option_id":37,"label":"4 gig ram","sort_order":2,"value":"4 gig ram"}]
[{"id":104,"option_id":34,"label":"80GB SATA","sort_order":0,"value":"80GB SATA"}]
[{"id":90,"option_id":24,"label":"Yes","sort_order":0,"value":"Yes"},{"id":91,"option_id":24,"label":"No","sort_order":1,"value":"No"}]
[{"id":102,"option_id":33,"label":"1GB DDR2 RAM (default)","sort_order":0,"value":"1GB DDR2 RAM (default)"},{"id":103,"option_id":33,"label":"2GB DDR2 RAM (+ $15.00)","sort_order":1,"value":"2GB DDR2 RAM (+ $15.00)"}]
```

If I use echo any of the following:

```
echo $allOptions;
json_encode($allOptions);
var_dump($allOptions);
```

I get a parse error when the data is returned to the mobile app. ie it is not recognising the result as a json array.

I am presuming:

1. That `$allOptions = array()` declares `$allOptions` as an array
2. I am populating `$allOptions` with each `$curlProductData` in the loop.

What am I doing wrong here ?

I am now using :

```
echo "[".implode(",\n",$allOptions)."]";
```

I am now getting the following returned :

```
[[{"id":112,"option_id":37,"label":"1 gig ram","sort_order":0,"value":"1 gig ram"},{"id":113,"option_id":37,"label":"2 gig ram","sort_order":1,"value":"2 gig ram"},{"id":114,"option_id":37,"label":"4 gig ram","sort_order":2,"value":"4 gig ram"}], [{"id":104,"option_id":34,"label":"80GB SATA","sort_order":0,"value":"80GB SATA"}], [{"id":90,"option_id":24,"label":"Yes","sort_order":0,"value":"Yes"},{"id":91,"option_id":24,"label":"No","sort_order":1,"value":"No"}], [{"id":102,"option_id":33,"label":"1GB DDR2 RAM (default)","sort_order":0,"value":"1GB DDR2 RAM (default)"},{"id":103,"option_id":33,"label":"2GB DDR2 RAM (+ $15.00)","sort_order":1,"value":"2GB DDR2 RAM (+ $15.00)"}]]
```

but I cannot get the mapping correct ?

MrWarby

Comment: What is throwing the parse error, is it the PHP, or the language that is receiving the output from your PHP (such as JavaScript)?

Comment: The language that is receiving the output from your PHP. Whenever I had done this before (simpler scenarios ) I can map the data to a mobile list. eg         var map2 = {
            label: 'display_name', 
            count: 'option_id', // this is the ID for the option
            value: 'id' // this is the id of the optionSet
}; But now I have to use label: ["0", "label"], 
 aside: ["1", "label"] but this is showing label from each array section and not a list. Am I making sense ???

Comment: Kind of, what language receives the `echo json_encode($allOptions)`?

Comment: I have got it working thanks. See below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution puts each of the items in a single array:

```
foreach($curlProductOptions as $value){
    //echo $value['option_id'].'<br>';
    $option_id = $value['option_id'];


    $product_url = $url.'/api/v2/options/'.$option_id.'/values.json';
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $product_url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
    $curlProductData = curl_exec($curl);

    foreach(json_decode($curlProductData, true) as $key => $value) {
        $allOptions[] = $value; // [] is quicker than array_push() for single items
    }

    curl_close($curl);
}
```

If you need your four groupings as in the question then:

The following solution puts each of the items in a single array:

```
foreach($curlProductOptions as $value){
    //echo $value['option_id'].'<br>';
    $option_id = $value['option_id'];


    $product_url = $url.'/api/v2/options/'.$option_id.'/values.json';
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $product_url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
    $curlProductData = curl_exec($curl);

    $allOptions[] = json_decode($curlProductData, true);

    curl_close($curl);
}
```

Now `json_encode($allOptions)` will give you a valid json String. The problem was you were trying to pass 4 json strings when only 1 was supposed to be read.

Comment: Thanks @akshey2598 The first section above gave me the correct result. Not sure why but I'll get my head around it soon....

Answer (score 1):

You are outputting several arrays after each other. You can only have one JSON object at once.

Best would be to stick to arrays and use `echo json_encode($curlProductData)` to output the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting a parser error, it's probably because there's a missing semicolon after `echo $curlProductData.'<br>'`

Answer (score 0):

```
$curlProductData = curl_exec($curl);
array_push($allOptions,$curlProductData);
```

The problem is that `curl_exec` is returning a string - that string may be a JSON string, but it's still a string.

Your final `echo json_encode($allOptions)` would be an array of strings, not a multidimensional array as you might be expecting.

What you can try is `echo "[".implode(",\n",$allOptions)."]";` as this will result in a multidimensional array.

However keep in mind that this must be done *after* the loop. If you do it while you're still inside the loop, you will end up with multiple outputs, which causes a problem.

Comment: I have used your code and update my question with the results at the bottom